Which higher-order terms require 4th-order integration of quadratically-constrained dynamics?
I was interested in demonstrating the notion of geodesics in constrained motion and prepared the calculation of force-free motion on the unit sphere, following Hertz' take on mechanics. Since the constraints could be arbitrary and the principal would still apply, I wanted to set up the system in x,y,z rather than constraining motion to $r=1$ in a spherical coordinate system.
To do that we consider the movement of a point mass constrained to the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We let the point be a free mass located at $\boldsymbol{r}(x,y,z)=x(t)\mathbf{e}_x+y(t)\mathbf{e}_y+z(t)\mathbf{e}_z$ with the holonomic constraint $$g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1.$$
We get then
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{r}}}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{r}} &= \lambda(t)\nabla g(x,y,z) \\
m\ddot{\mathbf{r}} &= \lambda(t) \nabla g(x,y,z)
\end{align}
which delivers 4 equations
\begin{align}
m\ddot{x} -2\lambda x  &=0 \\
m\ddot y -2 \lambda y &=0 \\
m\ddot z -2 \lambda z &=0 \\
x^2+y^2+z^2-1&=0. 
\end{align}
We multiply each equation by its coordinate and add together
\begin{align}
m\ddot{x}x+m\ddot yy+m\ddot zz &= 2\lambda (x^2+y^2+z^2) \\
\frac m2(\ddot{x}x+\ddot yy+\ddot zz ) &= \lambda.
\end{align}
Using the second time derivative of $g$ we have
$$\dot x^2+\dot y^2 +\dot z^2 = -(\ddot{x}x+\ddot yy+\ddot zz )
$$
we obtain
$$\lambda = -\frac m2(\dot x^2+\dot y^2 +\dot z^2) = -\frac m2 \|\dot{\boldsymbol{r}}\|^2
$$
to get
\begin{align}
m\ddot{x} +m(\dot x^2+\dot y^2 +\dot z^2) x &=0 \\
m\ddot y +m(\dot x^2+\dot y^2 +\dot z^2) y &=0 \\
m\ddot z + m(\dot x^2+\dot y^2 +\dot z^2) z &=0 \\ 
\end{align}
or
$$m\ddot{\mathbf{r}} +m\|\dot{\mathbf{r}}\|^2 \mathbf{r} = 0.
$$
To demonstrate I integrated this first with a leapfrog integrator and found my point mass was not staying on the sphere, but was converging to a wrong result. After calling myself completely into question, I decided to try the Yoshida 4th-order integrator and got near-perfect results (constraints, conservation, etc.). I tried the problem in spherical coords and was also not conserving energy (although constraints satisfied).

What is so high-order about the problem that second-order integration won't work? How would one analyse the needed integration order?

Are you sure about this "Using the second time derivative of g we have
$\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2=−(\ddot{x}x+\ddot{y}y+\ddot{z}z)$?

well after calling myself completely into question, yes. The first derivative being $2\dot xx + 2\dot yy + 2\dot zz$

Wouldn't that require $\ddot{g}=0$? Is that condition true? Also, why solve it in Cartesian instead of the more straight-forward spherical coordinates?

FWIW, I suspect there's something screwy in your derivation as your EOM (your last equation) does not appear to line up with expected equations (cf. this Physics.SE post).

You need to be careful in applying leapfrog to your EoM's since you have a velocity dependence on the force. You can have an appropriate second-order solver if you derive it using the same principles.
You can derive a Verlet analogue using the discretized least action principle:
$$
S = h\sum_n \frac1{2h^2}(\vec r_{n+1}-\vec r_n)^2-F_n(r_n-1)
$$
with $h$ the time step. You get the equations of motion:
$$
\frac1{h^2}(\vec r_{n+1}+\vec r_{n-1}-2\vec r_n) = F_n\hat r_n
$$
with $F_n$ chosen to normalise $r_n$. This gives you an implicit scheme:
$$
F_n = \frac{||\vec r_{n+1}+\vec r_{n-1}||-2}{h^2}\\
\vec r_n=\frac{\vec r_{n+1}+\vec r_{n-1}}{|| \vec r_{n+1}+\vec r_{n-1}||}
$$
which you can make explicit using the normalising constraints:
$$
\vec r_{n+1}=-\vec r_{n-1}+2(\vec r_{n-1}\cdot\vec r_n)\vec r_n
$$
In practice, due to finite precision issues, it is numerically unstable, and you should rather use:
$$
\vec r_{n+1}=-\vec r_{n-1}+\lambda_n\vec r_n
$$
with $\lambda_n$ chosen so that $\vec r_{n+1}$ is normalized without assuming that $\vec r_n,\vec r_{n-1}$ are. Without accounting for numerical error, the two approaches are formally equivalent, reserve the holonomic constraint and energy.
You can convert this Verlet analogue into leapfrog by inspection or by amending the least action principle. The new EoM's are:
$$
\begin{align}
\vec r_{n+1} &= \vec r_n +h\vec v_{n+1/2} & \vec v_{n+1/2} &= \vec v_{n-1/2}+hF_n\hat r_n
\end{align}
$$
with the same force as previously. Similarly, you can find it implicitly, explicitly numerically unstable or explicit numerically stable.
In short, there is no need for higher order solvers for your problem. You just need to be careful with how you implement your solver and watch out for numerical instabilities due to finite precision issues.

interesting! thanks. Do you have any reference for the discrete least action principal and its variation I can read up on? How would this work for e.g. a constraint function that was for an ellipsoid rather than the sphere?

Glad it helped. Yes, this generalises to any holonomic constraint. The trick is that the force is along the normal of the surface at position $\vec r_n$ with the leapfrog velocity times surrounding it $v_{n-1/2},v_{n+1/2}$. For the discrete least action, I first read about it in Lie group Integrators by Keenan Crane.

To answer the titular question: there isn't such a rule. Effectively, it's up to you as the researcher to determine the best ODE scheme to use to solve the problem based on your wants.
For instance, if you are demanding high accuracy, you will want to use the highest order scheme available to you. On the other hand, if you are demanding speed you might be more interested in lower order schemes. For problems that require conserving energy, you will likely be restricted to symplectic methods. If you have a stiff system, then you'll have to use an implicit scheme.
Running your system through a bunch of schemes is pretty simple when you have a small system (in both number of variables & total time steps) as you can get a result to compare in a few seconds. When you have a larger system, it's a little more troublesome if the simulation takes hours/days.
See this Math.SE post or this one for other suggestions. There may be other suggestions on SciComp.SE, but I'm not sure.

As an aside: since the constraint force in this case must be perpendicular to the surface, $\nabla g\cdot\dot{\mathbf{x}}=0$, then you could write $\ddot{\mathbf{x}}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{x}}=0$ which may be a more tractable way to solve the problem.

Alternatively, since constraints reduce the degrees of freedom, you can use $g=0$ to imply that $z=\pm\left(r^2-x^2-y^2\right)^{1/2}$ to eliminate $z$ from the system of equations.

Thanks. I added an image to show what I am talking about. My question is not about these problems in general, it is about this one. This one is a non-stiff, non-dissipative system. For me it clearly needs a symplectic integrator. My question is really directed at the second-order ODE with quadratic constraints. I would expect this to be solved by a quadratic integrator but clearly the integration is missing some important high-order terms. Eliminating z is an option, but I have essentially eliminated the constraint instead. As an exercise I find the problem interesting as stated.

You have 3 questions between the title and the body; 2 of them are explicitly about the generic case I address in this answer (to wit: the title and last question). If you want a more stable integrator that involves velocity-dependent forces, you could see this answer of mine.

Thank you. I apologise if my question wasn't asking the thing I wanted to know exactly, but for me it was the behaviour of the integrator in the face of simple equations/constraints that surprising. I didn't see the problem with the velocity dependence on the velocity and for me this is the crux of the issue. I'm going to give the 'correct' answer to LPZ because I think he/she has explained what the cause is.
